# Fetch number of results from Google News for a given time range

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to get the total number of news articles published for a list of keywords between a specified time period (Like last six months).

I've tried to use scrapy library to **scrape** google news but I'm unable to get results for the specified time period using the below code:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2019%2Ccd_max%3A8%2F1%2F2019&tbm=nws&ei=1tJXXfHLM4-S9QO07onwCg&q=%22Apple+Inc%22&oq=%22Apple+Inc%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3.48094.50359.0.51273.9.9.0.0.0.0.318.893.0j2j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.3.752....0.2cwnwIbhfS4']

def parse(self, response):
    item = {
        'search_title': response.css('input#sbhost::attr(value)').get(),
        'results': response.css('#resultStats::text').get(),
    }
    yield item
```

I want to create a data frame as final output with the entity and number of results found on google news.

Answer (score 0):

The selectors seem to work, but accessing the page is forbidden by robotstxt.
You can overcome this by setting the following in your settings.py:
`ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False`.

Alternatively, you can put this in your class:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  custom_settings = {'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False}
```

Caution this can cause that Google bans your IP address, this can work for few pages but after will ask for captcha challenge

Comment: I'm getting this error now:  TCP connection timed out: 10060:

Comment: That’s probably the servers detecting your activity as that of a robot and choosing not to serve you.